# Can I change my Employer who has applied Green Card while Green Card is in Progress?

Tags: usa, greencard

I am working in USA with H1B VISA. I am planning to apply Green Card with the help of my employer. I am aware getting green card is a long term process.

However my only question is, after my Green Card process initiated can I change my employer? If yes at what stage it is safe to change and what stage I have to refrain to change my Employer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, under American Competitiveness in the Twenty-First Century Act (AC21, as it is usually referred to).

To be able to do so without interrupting the GC process, there are two conditions:

1. Your AOS petition (form I-485) must be filed and pending, and
2. The new job should be similar to the old one.

Otherwise the new employer would have to start the process all over again. Read more [here](http://www.immihelp.com/greencard/adjustmentofstatus/changing-employer.html).